# Finding K values for all poles of real parts are less than -2

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

I have an open loop transfer function with k > 0 as below:

$$
  L(s) = \dfrac{k}{s(s^2+8s+25)}
$$

Now for the closed loop transfer function, I would like to find the k value which makes all the real parts of poles less than -2. Below is how I get the closed-loop transfer function:

$$
  G(s) = \dfrac{L(s)}{1+L(s)} = \dfrac{k}{s^3+8s^2+25s+k}
$$

Yet, I have no idea or method to locate the value k. I have used the **Routh Criterion**, and found that the boundary is $$200 > k > 0$$

However, this does not provide any useful information for me, is there any better way to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make the variable change \$u=s+2\$ in the polynomial \$P(s)=s^3+8s^2+25s+k\$. The result is the polynomial
$$
Q(u)=P(u-2)=(u-2)^3+8(u-2)^2+25(u-2)+k=u^3 + 2u^2 + 5u + k - 26.
$$
The Routh-Hurwitz criterion for this polynomial gives us the conditions
\$k-26>0\$ and \$10>k-26\$, thus, \$26<k<36\$.

Since \$26<k<36\$ implies \${\rm Re}\; u<0\$, we also have \${\rm Re}\; (s+2)<0\$ and \${\rm Re}\; s<-2\$.

Comment: This is amazing and reasonable. Thank you for your help, you save my day!